# JavaApplet under Java 11+ / Edge (without Oracle)

Tags: java, oracle, internet-explorer, applet, microsoft-edge

Have to get some very old legacy Applet Running. The Applet original used JDK 1.4 and IE. The new system is Edge and OpenJDK 11 or higher.
In the old System, we used Oracle JDK 8 which implements an IE Plugin (Java Plug-in 11.321.2). On the Webpage (BlackBox) is a Link to start the "App". The Task Manager shows p2launcher.exe (Java(TM) Web Launcher).
I don't really know how to get rid of Oracle here.

By now I thought about OpenWebStart but there is no JNLP File. Or to build some Wrapper to load the Applet, but that's not so easy because the applet somehow interacts with the document from the webpage.

So is there someone with a good idea to get an old JavaApplet to run on Edge / Java 11+?

Comment: Have you considered moving away from Applets? Oracle APEX is a modern and excellent
 web based solution if your data is already housed in Oracle databases. It does require Oracle Database to be version 12.1.0.2 or later.

Comment: Form [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/faqs-edge-in-the-enterprise#does-microsoft-edge--chromium-based--support-activex-controls-or-bhos-like-silverlight-or-java), we can know that Edge doesn't support Java. If the Applet works in IE11, you can configure it to run in [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) on Edge.

Comment: @EJEgyed The app is third Party, so no way to change something on this side.

Comment: @YuZhou IE mode works fine but use the IE Java plugin, so the applet will still use the p2launcher.exe (oracle).

Comment: IE mode is the same as IE, so they should have the same behavior. And it is true that you cannot open Java Applets in Edge - they are not supported and won't be added in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Write a jnlp File
2. Install Azul IcedTeaWeb
3. Configure the deployment jre

1.This is heavily based on the applet to be replaced. Here is an example:

```
    <jnlp spec="1.5+" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" codebase="*applet origin*" href="file:///C:/Program Files/JNLP/myJnlpFile.jnlp">
      <information>
        <title>Some title</title>
        <vendor>some vendor</vendor>
        <description>some Description</description>
        <homepage href="http://*applet url*"></homepage>
        <offline-allowed/>
      </information>
      <security>
        <all-permissions/>
      </security>
      <resources>
        <j2se version="1.3+"></j2se>
            <jar href="http://*applet URL*/some.jar" download="eager" main="true"></jar> <!-- this can be found in the original applet / page code -->
            <jar href="http://*applet URL*/another.jar" download="eager"></jar>
      </resources>
      <applet-desc 
        name="Some name" 
        main-class="myAppletMainClass" 
        width="1000" 
        height="800"
        align="baseline">
                <!-- this is based on the Applets params, simply some name and value pairs -->
                <param name="code" value="myAppletMainClass">
                <param name="archive" value="http://*applet URL*/some.jar"> 
      </applet-desc>
    </jnlp>
```

2. Download and install (nothing changed during installation): [Azul IcedTeaWeb Download](https://www.azul.com/products/components/icedtea-web/)
3. cmd "C:\Program Files\IcedTeaWeb\WebStart\bin\itweb-settings.exe" -headless set deployment.jre.dir "C:\Program Files\Java\zulu8"
   (yes thats not Java 11 like I mentioned in the question, but is still supported by Azul until 2030 and it is only used for this application and not the whole system)

Thats how it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using our CheerpJ Applet Runner extension, available both for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein) and [Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/ebfcpaoldmijengghefpohddmfpndmic).

Full disclosure: I am CTO of the company maintaining the extension and lead dev of the CheerpJ technology.

The extension is free for non-commercial use on the public internet. For any internal website or enterprise use a license is required.

Please [get in touch](https://leaningtech.com/contact-us/?subject=CheerpJ%20Applet%20Runner%20Licensing#mailus) if interested.